# Iterate Dataset with unordered index in python

Tags: python

Good evening,

I hope you all doing well,

how i can iterate through a database with unordered indices

Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWNxh.png)

i want to iterate a dataset in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reset index and iterate through the index

```
df.reset_index()
```